# How to send body in restTemplate as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-resttemplate

It is possible to set "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in  HttpHeader, but I want to set for requestbody, could you please guide me?

sample json:

```
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "urlencoded",
                    "urlencoded": [
                        {
                            "key": "username",
                            "value": "Tohid",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "password",
                            "value": "*mk",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "grant_type",
                            "value": "password",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

code :

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, APPLICATION_URLENCODED.getValue());
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(gson.toJson(requestBody), headers);
```

Postman screenshot :
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found out that in "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" we have to use as following:

```
 MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        requestBody.add("username",propertyConfig.getUserName());

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);
```

Comment: Can you possibly post the full solution, please?

Comment: How to use MultiValueMap and LinkedMultiValueMap?

Comment: I wasted 6+ hours for this freaking answer. I kept thinking that the issue was because of my code or sth. Turned out that this is the only way. Using Map or JSONObject doesnt freaking work. 
Wasted my nearly entire day and my back is breaking :(

Comment: How can this work? headers.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");